# C - Control the Overflow (Insertion of values ​from the keyboard)

Tags: c, int, scanf, overflow

I am trying to limit the user adding minimum and maximum values to it:

```
int verificate( int num, int min,  int max) {
while( (num > max) || (num < min) ) {
    printf("\tBig number try again:");
    scanf(" %d",&num);
}
return num;
}
```

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX INT_MAX

void main() {
int num1;
scanf(" %d",&num1);
num1=verificate(num1,MIN,MAX);
printf("Number = %d",num1);
}
```

The problem I have is if the user inserts a bigger number `(num1>2147483647)` automatically the result is `1410065407`, and also if the user inserts the biggest negative value `(num1=-999999999999)` automatically the result is `-1215752191`. 
There's any way that I can control this? And make the user to insert again the value?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour

Comment: If `max == INT_MAX` then the comparison `num > max` will *never* be true. I suggest you use `unsigned` integers instead and the `%u` format, and check [what `scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) to make sure it worked or not. Optionally you could [read a whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) into a string, and [convert it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) with validation checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` behavior on integer conversion overflow is undefined.

Use `fgets()` to read all input.  Ditch `scanf()`.

Use `strtol()` to parse the string: better error handling and overflow detection.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// return true when good
// return false on EOF    
bool verificate(int *dest, int min, int max) {
  char buf[80];
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    long num = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
    //  numeric input?     overflow?           >= min?       <= max? 
    if (endptr > buf && errno != ERANGE && num >= min && num <= max) {
      *dest = (int) num;
      return true;
    }
    printf("\tNon-numeric input or out of %d %d range:\n", min, max);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Sample usage

```
#define MIN 0
#define MAX INT_MAX

int main() {
  int num1 = 0;
  if (verificate(&num1, MIN, MAX) {
    printf("Number = %d",num1);
  } 
}
```

Comment: With `strtol()` you separate the number from the text and save the text in `endptr`, but I don't get how `endptr > buf` is only for numeric inputs. What do you compare?

Comment: @AzmahQi Simply research `strtol()`.  `endptr` is the end of the conversion. When input string in non-numeric text `endptr == buf`